# not controlled exception column VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

i am on a stack overflow with this.
Dunno how but the column **not controlled** has dissapeared from my VS2012 professional exceptions dialog. So i can't make it stop only on non controlled exceptions.

Any guess on how to get it back?

[image: WTF_NO_NotControlledOnly]

Thanks!

Comment: I have already solved it reseting VS configuration, i keep it open anyway for if someone knows a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

This disappears when you disable the "Just my code" setting in the debug options.

I suspect that's because if the debugger is debugging *all* of the code (not just yours) then a "user unhandled" exception is almost impossible to identify.